# How to fix LED fixture not turning off completely when the switch is off

Tags: led, led-driver, leakage-current, full-bridge

I have LED ceiling lights that are not completely turning off even when the switch is off.

[image]

Sometimes the brightness of the glow is just to much for me and finally decided to do something about it.

[This video by steeve mould](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uEmX5XClPY) tried to explain what is going on but did not offer a solution on how to fix the issue. The PCB on [8:11](https://youtu.be/1uEmX5XClPY?t=491) looked really similar to what mine uses. The solution to the problem though is on another [video by Electroboom](https://youtu.be/_bgUy6zA0ts?t=438) saying to place a 470 kohm resistor on the output of the rectifier.

[image]

The circuit that electroboom is using is not the exact same circuit as I have. So will it still work? And how do I calculate the value of the resistor for my circuit?

Comment: There are commercially available solutions for this, basically consisting of a PTC resistor you connect in parallell with the light. Google "LED base load" and you will find loads of different models. No need to do potentially dangerous modifications of your lamps.

Comment: Ah, usually there is 200VAC converted to 40V~80V DC constant current source, driving a series, perhaps 24 1W LEDs. You can do something to "switch off" the 80V DC CCS. Reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543982/whats-the-voltage-used-to-power-leds-inside-an-led-light-bulb.

Comment: Classic issue. Can you place a small incandescent load on the same circuit?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny so this is a very common problem for LED light then, that there are commercial products to fix these issues

Comment: @winny Unfortunately i cant, as there would be this one awkward light that would not match the aesthetics of the rest of them. I would not also be comfortable of placing an incandescent and hiding it somewhere.